# Merge results in merge-conflicts to files I didn't alter

Tags: git, open-source, git-merge, sapui5, git-fork

I have been working with a fork of [SAP's OpenUI5 repository](https://github.com/SAP/openui5) for a while and would like to merge in the latest changes from another (more recent) release branch. **In essence, I want to "upgrade" my fork.**

My fork point was [`aa08b45865b8db4457bc6c626754c58230811b43`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/aa08b45865b8db4457bc6c626754c58230811b43) which points to a commit reachable by the `rel-1.28` release branch.

I started my "fork" off a release branch, rather than `master`, because I was worried that working off of `master` would be unstable and have commits that overlap multiple releases.

My upgrade target is `1.34.6` which is pointed to by [`cb4d1be36087ed7f1dfbde44884782774fceb51b`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/cb4d1be36087ed7f1dfbde44884782774fceb51b).

The ultimate command that I need to run is effectively:

```
git checkout aa08b45        # my original fork-point
git checkout -b myForkPoint # local branch
git merge cb4d1be           # merge in 1.34.6 code
```

But this results in many merge-conflicts to files that I didn't alter. (I'm guessing because I'm trying to merge in a ref that is not reachable to my `HEAD`).

Using `merge-base` and comparing commits manually between release branches and `master` (such as [`63596f`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/63596fba8090d697ea6012f003a2ba39ac7907e4) and [`b23117`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/b23117e9d845a4dcaa488643cad595870232c781)) it seems that OpenUI5's release branches are populated by `cherry-pick`ing commits from `master`. The release branches are not merged back into `master` one they are done being updated.

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor aa08b45 origin/master; echo $?; # prints 1
git merge-base --is-ancestor cb4d1be origin/master; echo $?; # prints 1
```

So, perhaps this branching model is not conducive to working off the public release branches?

Regardless, is there a clean way to "upgrade" my fork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was to *create our own merge-base* by merging the two release branches together and having the later-release (1.34.6) side win all conflicts (using a merge-strategy).

Then, merge that merge-base into our own forked branch.

This way, the contents of each release branch are reachable from our fork-point, so all conflicts from the second merge will only be from the changes that we introduced.

Here are the steps:

```
# first create the merge-base
git branch merge-1.34.6 1.34.6
git checkout merge-1.34.6
git merge rel-1.28 -s ours 1.34.6

# next merge the merge-base branch into us
git checkout myForkPoint
git merge merge-1.34.6
...fix conflicts, stage and commit...
```